# How do you store datetime in MongoDB given that what I've tried has failed?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to insert a datetime in MongoDB but I can not.

Here is the method I used:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    date : {
       type : Date 
          }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('test', testSchema);
```

Comment: what do you mean, "has failed"?

Comment: just the date is inserted. hour, minute and second are not inserted

Comment: Show the code you used for insertion (and the querying, while we're at it)

Answer (score 0):

```
try { 
    Mongo mongo = new Mongo("yourhost", 27017);
    DB db = mongo.getDB("yourdb");

    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("yourColl");                  
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    Date date = (Date)formatter.parse("2-Jun-2012")
    BasicDBObject time = new BasicDBObject("ts", date);
    collection.save(time);
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (MongoException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// You just add **default: Data.now** in your Schema. it will works 100%

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    date : {
       type : Date,
       default : Data.now
          }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('test', testSchema);
```